# final variable is not showing error in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, final

```
const order = ['margherita', 'pepperoni'];

var total = 0.0;

for (var item in order) {

    final price = pizzaPrices[item];

    if (price != null) {

      total += price;

    } else {

      print('$item pizza is not on the menu');

    }

}
print('Total: \$$total');
```

Here final variable is accessed twice, one is final price = 'margherita' and another one is price = 'pepperoni'....why it is not showing an error as the final price variable is accessed twice.....but the below code is showing the error...

```
var item = 'margherita';

final price = pizzaPrices[item];

item = 'pepperoni';

price = pizzaPrices[item];

print(price);
```

here it is showing error cause final variable price is accessed twice by dartpad

Answer (score 0):

in the first example, you are defining a final variable once in the block. in every iteration, it removes and reinitializes the variables. so you are changing it only once. but in the second example, you are changing a variable twice in a block. so you will get an error.